# Missing log in RMI program

Tags: java, rmi, aspectj

I managed to write simple program which should simulate passing control in system consisting of three components. But I am not sure if I've done it correctly, because logs don't look like I was expecting.

I couldn't find mistake. Is it in aspectJ-part or in RMI-part?

RMIServer

```
public class RMIServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException,
            MalformedURLException {
        LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
        HelloIF hello = new Hello();
        Naming.rebind("server.Hello", hello);
        System.out.println("Server is ready.");
    }
}
```

RMIServer2

```
public class RMIServer2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException,
            MalformedURLException, NotBoundException, InterruptedException {

            //LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1098);
            LocateRegistry.getRegistry(1099);
        ByeIF bye = new Bye();
        Naming.rebind("server.Bye", bye);
        System.out.println("Server-Client is ready.");

    }
```

RMIClient

```
public class RMIClient {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException,
                MalformedURLException, NotBoundException, InterruptedException {

            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost");
            ByeIF bye = (ByeIF) registry.lookup("server.Bye");
            System.out.println(bye.farewell(Thread.currentThread().getName()));
        }
}
```

Hello

```
public class Hello extends UnicastRemoteObject implements HelloIF {

    public Hello() throws RemoteException {
    }

    public String greeting(String c) throws RemoteException,
            InterruptedException {
        return "Good morning!";
    }
}
```

Bye

```
public class Bye extends UnicastRemoteObject implements ByeIF {

    public Bye() throws RemoteException {
    }

    public String farewell(String c) throws RemoteException,
            InterruptedException, NotBoundException {
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost");
        HelloIF hello = (HelloIF) registry.lookup("server.Hello");
        System.out.println(hello.greeting(Thread.currentThread().getName()));
        return "Bye bye!";
    }

}
```

And logs look:

```
[2012-08-03 11:06:18,582] [request1343984778582] [public static void hello.RMIClient.main(java.lang.String[])]
[2012-08-03 11:06:18,738] [request1343984778582] [public java.lang.String hello.Bye.farewell(java.lang.String)]
[2012-08-03 11:06:18,785] [request1343984778582] [public java.lang.String hello.Hello.greeting(java.lang.String)]
[2012-08-03 11:06:18,785] [request1343984778582] [public java.lang.String hello.Hello.greeting(java.lang.String)]
[2012-08-03 11:06:18,847] [request1343984778582] [public static void hello.RMIClient.main(java.lang.String[])]
```

So one log is missing - `Bye.farewell()`

I don't know why aspectJ cannot see when the method ends.

```
@Aspect
public class ReportingAspect {

    // --------------------------------------LOGGER

    static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ReportingAspect.class);

    // --------------------------------------POINTCUTS

    @Pointcut("execution(public static void hello.RMIClient.main(String[]))")
    public void requestStart() {
    }

    @Pointcut("(execution(String greeting(..)) && args(context)) || "
            + "(execution(String farewell(..)) && args(context))")
    public void RMImethodStart(String context) {
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(String greeting(..)) || "
            + "execution(String farewall(..)) || "
            + "execution(public static void hello.RMIClient.main(String[]))")
    public void general() {
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(public static void hello.RMIServer.main(String[])) || "
            + "execution(public static void hello.RMIServer2.main(String[]))")
    public void setLoggingFile() {
    }

    // --------------------------------------ADVICES

    @Before("requestStart()")
    public void setLoggerAndThreadName(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
        Thread.currentThread().setName("request" + System.currentTimeMillis());
        report(joinPoint);
    }

    @Before("RMImethodStart(context)")
    public void setThreadName(JoinPoint joinPoint, String context) {
        Thread.currentThread().setName(context);
        report(joinPoint);
    }

    @Before("setLoggingFile()")
    public void setProperties() {
        PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
    }

    @After("general()")
    public void generateReport(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        report(joinPoint);
    }

    /*//!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    @After("execution(public String hello.Bye.farewell(String))")
    public void test(JoinPoint joinPoint)
    {
        report(joinPoint);
    }*/

    // ---------------------------------------REPORT
    void report(JoinPoint jp) {
        logger.error(jp.getSignature().toLongString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `RMIClient` isn't a client at all, it is a server. I don't see how this code can possibly work. `RMIServer` creates a Registry on port 1099 and binds a Hello to that. `RMIClient` creates a Registry on port 1098 and binds a Bye to that. `RMIClient2` looks up a Bye on the default Registry port which is 1099. I don't see how that can possibly succeed. This cannot be the real code.

Comment: @EJP As I've already said: I am not sure if I've done it correctly - I am completely new to RMI. My idea was: Client2 use method Bye.farewell which use Hello.greeting(). Isn't it OK? How port numbers should be changed? Still don't get it. (btw it is a real code, it prints "Bye bye" and "Good morning")

Comment: 1. Rename `RMIClient` to `RMIServer2`. 2. Change `createRegistry(1098)` to `getRegistry(1099)`. 3. Run it and post your results here: edit them into your post, and also edit the code to reflect the code you are actually running. And by 'results' I include exceptions.

Comment: I see why it worked. You called createRegistry(1098) but you did nothing without, you just calling Naming.bind() instead, which uses port 1099. You can remove getRegistry(1099) completely from the 2nd server. Tour question is now about AspectJ, not RMI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find a bug that you don't understand, try to reduce the problem. In your case, how about a few good old `System.out.println()` in the actual code to see what really happens?

Also, I don't see any exception handling. Depending on your version of Java, exceptions in `main()` might be swallowed.

Comment: There isn't any exception, I've checked. I know I should try reduce my problem, but I have no idea where I've made mistake.

Comment: But you can be sure that `System.out.println()` works, so use that to see if it gives you different results. That will give you an idea where you made the mistake.

Comment: Or maybe with different words: If the complicated approach (aspectJ, logging) fails, try something more simple to make sure everything else works correctly.

Comment: You're great programmer if you know how to print message after `return` statement without using aspects. Both messages `Good morning` and `bye bye` are displayed, so the problem is hidden and `System.out.println()` didn't help (I tried). Program is so simple I couldn't find a lot of places to put `syso` in it.

Comment: That's simple: `try { ...; return } finally { System.out.println("..."); }`

Comment: If everything else works, are you sure the server could be started? Maybe an old instance is hanging around somewhere. Do you see `Server is ready`? And if you see it, are you sure the classes were compiled? Check the time stamps on the disk to make sure.

Comment: Thanks :) so message in `finally` wasn't printed (in method `farewell()`) but `Bye bye` was. That looks very weird...

Comment: I restarted eclipse, cleaned and builed project and there it is: `Exception in thread "request1343914242519" java.rmi.NotBoundException: server.Bye`

Comment: Ask a new question; you can copy most things from this one. Also check that you have "Build Automatically" enabled in the Eclipse preferences. And if you use Maven, either never build from the command line **or** make Eclipse compile into a different folder.